Excel -- Increasing the Count based on the fixed Multiple w/ Extra Rules
Simple formulas for increasing the count based on fixed multiple in columnC are either
=IF(B1>0,INT(1/60)+1)
=IF(B1>0,ROUNDUP(B1/60,0)
Due to the extra rules these has to be modified into something more complex or replaced something else entirely.
RULES
1.) Increase the C-count by +1 passing or equalling a multiple of 60 in B.
---ColumnB might not present an exact multiple of 60 (x60)  eg. 117→ 121 directly, over 120 = x60).
2.) Decrease the C-count by -1 each instance A is positive.
---Using the formulas above would invalidate -1 in next row(s).
3.) Maintain the C-count value if(and( m
----- simultaneous passing x60 & A is positive = +1 -1
----- A-value is negative.



-1
18
1

default= 1




-1
30
1




-1
36
1

same, A<0


-1
42
1




-1
48
1




-1
54
1




-1
58
1




-1
62
2

+1, passing x60


-1
66
2




-1
72
2




-1
78
2




-1
84
2




1
90
1

-1, A>0


-1
94
1




-1
98
1




-1
101
1




-1
104
1




-1
107
1




-1
113
1




-1
117
1




-1
121
1

+1, passing x60


-1
125
2




-1
129
2




-1
133
2




-1
137
2




-1
141
2




-1
145
2




-1
149
2




-1
153
2




-1
157
2




-1
161
2




-1
165
2




-1
168
2




-1
171
2




-1
174
2




-1
177
2




1
180
2

simultaneous +1, -1


1
184
1




1
188
0






@admin mistakes corrected, clear now

Try this:

The default value must be manually inputed (first 1)
=IF(ROUNDDOWN(B3/60,0)>ROUNDDOWN(B2/60,0),C2+1,C2)+IF(A3>0,-1,0)


Foxfire And Burns And Burns' solution inspired me to create the following function which spills the result using Office 365 including the initial default: 1, so this function can start calculating from row 1, but would also work if it starts at a different row:
=LET(a,A1:A39,
     b,B1:B39,
SCAN(,SEQUENCE(ROWS(a)),LAMBDA(x,y,
     IF(y-1,
        x+(INT(INDEX(b,y)/60)>INT(INDEX(b,y-1)/60))-(INDEX(a,y)>0),
        1))))

Where we first use LET to name ranges A1:A39 and B1:B39 a and b respectively.
Then we use scan to get an iteration through these ranges. To do so we use SEQUENCE(ROWS(a)).
When the scan-lambda starts it's calculation it starts with y (the rows-sequence) being 1.
Initially the function checks IF(y-1,[calculation],1) meaning that y being 1 minus 1 it results in 0 for the initial y value which to the IF-functions means FALSE and results in the 1 always.
For any next y value y minus 1 is always an integer greater then 0, which to the IF-function means TRUE and results in the calculation.
The calculation sums the previous value (x) and the integer of the indexed current row of b divided by 60 being greater than that of the previous row. and minus one if the indexed current row of a is greater than 0.

Nice Solutions + the explanations.

A bit more verbose, for fun:
=LAMBDA(a,b,_default_c,
SCAN(_default_c, SEQUENCE(ROWS(a)),
LAMBDA(_c,_i,
LET(
_a, INDEX(a, _i),
_b, INDEX(b, _i),
_prev_b, INDEX(b, _i - 1),
_incr_if_B_passing_x60,  1 * (QUOTIENT(_b, 60) > QUOTIENT(_prev_b, 60)),
_decr_if_positive_A, -1 * (_a > 0),

IF(_i = 1, _c,
_c + _incr_if_B_passing_x60 + _decr_if_positive_A)
))))(A1:A39,B1:B39,1)

